# What does "such as" refer to?

Tags: grammar

Example Sentence: "Public tranportation such as train or bus."

Question: What do the words "such as" refer to?

Do the words "such as" refer to "public transportation" or to "train and bus"?

I had this question in my exam.

Comment: What research have you done into "such as"? What did it show you? I think your question may be better suited to English Language Learners stack exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "such as" always refers to the list that follows it. Here it clearly refers to train or bus and can be replaced by "like" or "for instance". If "such as" had to refer to "public transportation", then public transportation would have to follow as as a subset of a larger whole. For example, "Modes of transportation such as public transportation and private transportation enable people to travel over large distances." Have I made it more complicated?

Comment: You really helped me.The problem is that our teacher marked my answer like a mistake and said that "such is" always refers to a word in front of it!! Thank you very much)